# Install py[2]-numpy in Alpine Edge (Alpine 3.10 is current and has py[2]-numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, alpine-linux

Due to [`gdal`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=gdal&branch=edge) and [`proj`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=proj&branch=edge) (aka `proj4`) only being available in Alpine Edge ("testing" repository), I am locked to that branch.

The Python module `gdal` (not the above mentioned library) does not compile on Alpine Edge when using Python 3, so this locks me to using Python 2.

I get lots of errors like

```
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function 'CPLErr GDALDatasetShadow_SetGCPs2(GDALDatasetShadow*, int, const GDAL_GCP*, OSRSpatialReferenceShadow*)':
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4735:12: error: 'GDALSetGCPs2' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'GDALSetGCPs'?
     4735 |     return GDALSetGCPs2( self, nGCPs, pGCPs, (OGRSpatialReferenceH)hSRS );
          |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
          |            GDALSetGCPs
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function 'PyObject* _wrap_EscapeString(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)':
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:7850:63: warning: 'int PyObject_AsReadBuffer(PyObject*, const void**, Py_ssize_t*)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     7850 |       int res = PyObject_AsReadBuffer(obj0, &safeBuf, &safeLen);
          |                                                               ^
    In file included from /usr/include/python3.7m/Python.h:147,
                     from extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:173:
    /usr/include/python3.7m/abstract.h:489:17: note: declared here
      489 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyObject_AsReadBuffer(PyObject *obj,
          |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

which I assume are due to this Python version mismatch.

I need to use `py-numpy` (`py2-numpy`) + the `-dev` packages as well as `py2-matplotlib`, but these are not available in the Edge branch repository. That one only has those packages precompiled for Python 3.

```
OK:  ---> Running in a83422b2e066
OK: fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:

OK:   py-numpy (missing):
    required by: world[py-numpy]
  py-numpy-dev (missing):
    required by: world[py-numpy-dev]
  py2-matplotlib (missing):
    required by: world[py2-matplotlib]
```

The packages of numpy and matplotlib exist for Python 2 in the 3.10 branch.

Is there a way I can use/install them in the Edge branch?

This is the relevant part of my Dockerfile

```
RUN apk --update --no-cache add --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
      build-base \
      gdal \
      gdal-dev \
      proj \
      proj-dev \
      python2 \
      python2-dev \
      py-numpy \
      py-numpy-dev \
      py2-pillow \
      py2-matplotlib \
      py2-pip && \
    \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade subprocess32 cycler gdal arrow && \
...
```